# Splash screen in Windows Store apps

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps, splash-screen

I am developing Windows Store Apps for Tablet using VS2012. Right now i am creating splash screen for my application. My requirement is **the splash screen should be display full screen in my app**.
but it is working as Center of the screen. Can any one help regarding this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that there is no way to create an official splash screen that is full-screen.  A splash screen has to use a 620 x 300 pixel image, where it is a normal splash screen or an [extended splash screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700390.aspx).  However, you can match the background color around the splash screen to the color of the splash screen image (using the [instructions you already found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh465346.aspx)), which makes it appear like a full-screen image, even though much of it is just color.

Comment: I think that states the situation pretty clear. You're right, Jen.

Comment: Jen's right, though robert.oh does mention a workaround using a regular xaml page. The problem with this approach is that your app load has to be EXTREMELY fast. This means removing resources from your App.Xaml and removing as many lines as possible from App.xaml.cs OnLaunched. Note that this is not a best practice and it may even fail store certification. Definitely best to stick with the recommended splash screen and then add an additional loading screen if necessary. See Jetpack Joyride for an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK a splash screen has to be centered, but maybe a valid work around would be to create a start page (regular xaml) and have this one displayed as initial screen as soon as the splash screen is gone.
But this would mean that your startup time has to be quite fast.

Maybe it's an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

- Open the "package.appxmanifest" manifest file.
  The manifest should automatically open in the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 Manifest Designer.
- Open the Application UI tab and scroll down to the Splash Screen
  section. If you are still using project defaults, you should see the
  "images\splashscreen.png" path in the Splash Screen field. If you
  open "package.appxmanifest" in a text editor, you should see
  SplashScreen element as a child of the VisualElements element. For
  example, the default splash screen markup in the manifest file looks
  like this:

XML

> `{ <SplashScreen Image="images\splashscreen.png" /> }`

- Change the splash screen image by using the Browse... button and
  confirm that the image was added to your Visual Studio project.
  Important  The splash screen image you choose must be 620 x 300
  pixels using a 1x scaling factor.
- In the Background Color field of the Splash Screen section, set the
  background color to display with your splash screen image. You can
  enter either the name of a color or '#' and the hex value of a color.
- Setting a background color for your splash screen is optional. If you
  do not specify a color, the splash screen background color defaults
  to the Tile background color (the color in the Background Color field
  of the Tile section in the Application UI tab). If you open
  package.appxmanifest in a text editor, the Tile background color is
  specified via the BackgroundColor attribute of the VisualElements
  element.

Comment: I already read this article 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh465346.aspx

Can you explain How can i get my image to full screen of the app. Right now it is getting in center of the screen.
 Waiting for your valuable reply...

Answer (score -1):

my workaround is make a 620x300 splash .png image with alpha background, so its not a full 620x300 image. the image itself is just a 300x300 logo. my suggestion is just make a small center image (your app logo or something else) and make it blend to the background (gradient or alpha)